# Password Regex allowing © symbol at end of the word

Tags: regex, coldfusion, railo

I'm using the following Regex to ensure that a password only has alphabetic and numeric characters.

```
if(! reFind("^[[:alnum:][:punct:]]", this.password)) {
                this.addError(property="Password", message="Password must contain only letters, numbers, or punctuation marks.");
            }
```

If I add a copyright `©` character to the beginning of the word, the reFind blocks it; if I add it to the end of the word, it goes through. So `©abcd` does not go through, while `abcd©` does.

I want to make sure that I only allow alphanumeric and punctuation characters in my passwords.

Comment: _"I want to make sure that I only allow alphanumeric and punctuation characters in my passwords."_ - why!? There is ***no*** valid reason to do this. Passwords get encrypted, so the type and number of characters they contain is irrelevant.

Comment: @Peter, I thought about that. I'm encrypting everything, any way. I want to err on the safe side and not have to worry about none latin-based characters. I don't understand the implications of their use in  passwords.

Comment: There are no implications - you use the same algorithm to encrypt the password when registering and when authenticating, so it doesn't matter what characters or character sets are involved - it's just a string of data to the encryption algorithm. There's no reason to block them.

Comment: @Peter, fair enough, so if I understand you correctly, there is no need for a regex here (unless I want to force my users to use a certain combination of characters for extra safety)! And that the database will live on without any issues... thanks!

Comment: Yep. Most encryption algorithms output hex digits, so you just need to know the appropriate length and that's it. And yeah, the only regex you'd need is to enforce a specific complexity - although be careful there too, since overly complex rules can encourage people to use the same password for everything (very bad), and allowing a sentence of words can potentially be _more_ secure (and easier to remember) than something like "P45$Word".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regular expression just ensures that the first character is alphanumeric and/or punctuation. You want to ensure that *every* character is alphanumeric and/or punctuation. You can use either of these:

```
if(reFind("[^[:alnum:][:punct:]]", this.password))

if(! reFind("^[[:alnum:][:punct:]]*$", this.password))
```

(Note: these also differ from yours in that they allow a zero-length password. I figure that that's O.K., since you'll want to give a different error message in that case.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if(!reFind("^[[:alnum:][:punct:]]+$", this.password))
```

Comment: That will not allow the following: `abc123`

Comment: `\w` includes punctuation? Is this some special ColdFusion thing?

Comment: `\w` will not allow unicode characters, which is one of my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you write something like:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: "I want to make sure that I only allow alphanumeric **and punctuation** characters in my passwords."

Comment: @Kent, this also does not allow accents in unicode characters.

Comment: yep, I just read the 1st line, he didn't mention punctuation. :(